# How to align the left parts in 2-nd and 4th lines?

Tags: align, cases

I need to aling the 2nd and 4th lines in the case:

[image]

I have tried to use the & sign in different places of the code:

```
\begin{equation}
    f(t) =
           \begin{cases}  
                         D, &\Delta P_i(t) \leq -E, \\ 
                         d, \quad -E < &\Delta P_i(t) \leq 0 , \\
                         e, &\Delta P_i(t) = 0 , \\
                         r, \quad 0 < &\Delta P_i(t)\leq  E, \\
                         R, & \Delta P_i(t) >E, \\
           \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cases` environment is a wrapper around an `array` with column specifications `@{}l@{\quad}l@{}`, and as such it does not support multiple alignments. Just use directly an `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f(t) =
\left\{
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}% as in {cases}
\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}r@{\;}l@{}}
    D, &      & \Delta P_i(t) \leq -E, \\ 
    d, & -E < & \Delta P_i(t) \leq 0 , \\ % <-- you sure about \leq ??
    e, &      & \Delta P_i(t) = 0 , \\
    r, &  0 < & \Delta P_i(t) \leq E, \\
    R, &      & \Delta P_i(t) > E,
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Between the second and third column I added `\;`, which is the spacing (`\thickmuskip`) around math relations.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `empheq` and the `alignedat` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={f(t)) = \empheqlbrace}]{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
     & D, & & & \Delta P_i(t) & \leq -E, \\
     & d, &\quad -E & < {}& \Delta P_i(t) & \leq 0 , \\ % <-- you sure about \leq ??
    & e, & & & \Delta P_i(t) & = 0 , \\
     & r, & 0 & <{} & \Delta P_i(t) & \leq E, \\
     & R, & & & \Delta P_i(t) & > E,
\end{alignedat}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]